# How delete targeting criterion with twurl?

Tags: curl, twitter

I am trying to use twurl to experiment with the Twitter ads API. I can do GETs pretty well, but trying to POST I am having issues. A simple example is deleteing a targeting_criterion:

```
twurl -H "https://ads-api.twitter.com" -X POST "/5/batch/accounts/XXXX/targeting_criteria" -d ‘[{"operation_type":"Delete","params":{"targeting_criterion_id":"m08op5"}}]’
```

The response is:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS","message":"This request is not properly authenticated"}],"request":{"params":{}}}
```

I get the same if I use `-r` instead of `-d`. But using the same credentials I am able to programatically delete via HTTP. I suspect the error response is masking some other goof I am making.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Thx!

Comment: Executing the above request with `account/XXXXX` in the path does correctly result in a proper Authentication error. I suspect the code was encountering `415 Unsupported Media Type`, correct? If so, I agree with the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding "Content-Type" request header by setting below option for twurl?:

`-A "Content-Type: application/json"`

It is required (See the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/campaign-management/api-reference/targeting-criteria#post-batch-accounts-account-id-targeting-criteria)):

> All parameters are sent in the request body and a Content-Type of application/json is required.

FYI, we also have a Developer Forum site where you can ask these kinds of questions by having appropriate categories. In this case, it's under the [Advertiser Tools and APIs](https://twittercommunity.com/c/advertiser-api)
 category.